# Outlook 365 - how to minimize blank area

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I upgraded recently to office 365 ProPlus and encountered some annoying things.

One of them is the too big blank area in Outlook 365 as shown below.
Is there any way to reduce this area?

**Office 365:**
[image]

**Outlook 2013** (there is no such blank area)

[image]

Comment: This is by design. You may submit your feedback to Outlook uservoice forum.[link](https://outlook.uservoice.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Perry for the link, I just did it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been recently implemented and the search bar is now at the top of the window. If it is not yet updated in your Outlook client, it should arrive soon.

[image]

- This is my Outlook client version where it appeared for the first time:
  `Version 2004 (Build 12730.20236 Click-to-Run)`
- Subscribed channel for Office updates:
  `Monthly Channel`